# How to return this to the beginning?

Tags: java

I'm trying to make the program return when going yes and then use system.exit if they pick no. But , I'm stuck at the yes part i simply don't know what to do :/

```
Scanner scan= new Scanner (System.in);

}
int end;
end = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog
        (null,"Do you like more transaction?","Transaction",JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
if (end ==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
}

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `do while` loop for this

```
int end;
do {
    // the code you want to repeat goes here
    end = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,"Do you like more transaction?","Transaction",JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
} while (end == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION);
```

No need to use `system.exit`, the program will end by itself.

Comment: Is there anyway to use like if else loop? Managed to make it work using do while code just want to ask if its possible to do it with if else loop. Thanks by the way ;)

Comment: @Yamiess `if else` is not a loop. The code inside those blocks will be executed one time only. There are 3 kinds of loops: `for`, `while` and `do while`

Comment: @Yamiess I don't think `for` loop is very usable here. You need to check `true` or `false` condition, `for` loop is more for known number of iterations.